# Can't log in to Pokemon Go with Google Account on my New Phone? Not an Option!

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

Upgraded from S4 to S7 Galaxy. Signed out of Pokémon Go on the S4. Downloaded Pokémon Go on S7 and I do not get the option to log in with my Google account. Only option is Pokémon Trainer Club. How can I get to a Google login on the new S7?

Answer (score 8):

This happens when the age you chose at the beginning is too young to have a google account. Go into your device's app settings and clear the cache and info of the Pokémon Go app. Then, choose an older age and you'll get your google sign in option back.